# QML flickering with Animations on images

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I'm writing a QML application that displays a collection images.
To display next and previous image I use a ParallelAnimation to animate the x coordinate translation but the result is ugly: images animate but there is a flicking during the animation.

I've tried with opengl viewport and some optimizations (see [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativeperformance.html)) but no success.

Comment: Which platform are you on and are you able to supply some code snippets to show what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

try adding view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
in main.cpp